# When do textarea change events not get triggered?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, backbone.js

I'm relying on the change event being triggered whenever the contents of the textarea changes. According to the [jquery docs](http://api.jquery.com/change/), this doesn't get triggered until the textarea loses focus. Under what circumstances could the event not be triggered? Would clsoing a page, going back, clicking on a link, etc, always cause the textarea to lose focus and be fired?

Or to put it another way, is it possible to leave a page without a focusses textarea losing input?

Comment: Must be be just the change event? There are plenty of other events; e.g. keyUp, keyDown, keyPress, focus, paste.

Comment: Because change is the event I'm using :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With differents tests, the change event is not triggered when:

- the user clicks on **any button of the browser** (back button, refresh, home button...) *(Chrome, Firefox amd Opera on Linux but triggered when click on adress bar)*
- the user uses shortcuts (f5, ctrl+u...) *(tested on Chrome + Firefox + Opera)*.

You can test an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/Atinux/S6TkP/

So I recommand you to use in addition keyUp and keyDown events on your input and textarea forms.

Comment: They all trigger for me in firefox. Is it browser specific?

Comment: I tested with Chrome, Opera and Firefox on Linux, and It depends with the browser. So yes It's browser specific.

Comment: Great answer, thanks! In the end, those constraints are actually fine for my use case, but it's great to know what they are.

Answer (score 2):

I would go to the W3c definition of the event.

[http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html][1]

> The change event occurs when a control loses the input focus and its
>   value has been modified since gaining focus. This event is valid for
>   `INPUT`, `SELECT`, and `TEXTAREA` element.
>
> - Bubbles: Yes
> - Cancelable: No
> - Context Info: None

Any time it loses focus, it should be fired.

Comment: I guess my question equates to "when does an input not lose focus?"

Answer (score 1):

On Safari and Chrome whenever you change the text the CHANGE event is fired. However, if you delete all the text then the CHANGE event is not fired anymore. This is a bug. This is why people use the KEYPRESS events as a workaround

Answer (score 0):

The event will be triggered but you won't be able to listen to it reliably. Form elements lose focus when a page is unloading but there is a race condition around when the even gets triggered and when the listeners get called. *If* your listener is called before the page is done unloading, you *might* get the callback but it's far from guaranteed.

If you want to be able to keep track of changes to a `textarea` more reliably you are better off listening to the `keypress` event.

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use keyUp/keyDown event cause the change event only fires when the textare/input was changed and the element lost its focus.