# Is it OK to ignore keydown events with keyCode = 229?

Tags: javascript, events, dart, keyboard-events, dartium

At the beginning I wanted to monitor changes to a `<input type="text">` in real time (for example, exactly when the user presses a key). The `onChange` event did not work because it is triggered only when the user presses Enter or removes focus from the input element. Then I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14433156/respond-immediately-to-textarea-changes-in-dart/14433159#14433159) on StackOverflow. I tried the code from that answer but the problem is that I do not want to be notified for key presses that do not represent printable characters, so I had to modify it in this way to make it verify that there are printable characters in the events:

```
...

textInputElement.onKeyDown.listen((KeyboardEvent ev) {
  if (new String.fromCharCode(ev.keyCode).length > 0) {
    callAFunction();
  }
});

...
```

(+ the same change for the `onKeyUp` event)

When I tested this in Dartium I saw that by focusing the input element and then pressing any key, a `keydown` event is triggered with `ev.keyCode = ev.which = 229` and `ev.charCode = 0`. Immediately after this event, another `keydown` event is triggered with the correct `ev.keyCode = ev.which` of the pressed key and `ev.charCode = 0`. I did not understand where this 229 key was coming from but I saw that it is a printable character, `å`. I searched the Internet and I have found that others have this issue, and sometimes they are using other programming languages and technologies. One relevant link is [this](https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2/issues/2482) and the chosen fix is in [this very small commit](https://github.com/hitosu/select2/commit/7c1ceb8fd9d19d072585a44c5d07c4d480f1ac54) - they chose to ignore all events which have `keyCode = 229` with the explanation that recent versions of Chrome/Chromium/WebKit started to send these keydown events before every standard keyboard events, and that their meaning is that the *user pressed some button. but input method is still processing that* or *input method editor is processing key input*.

My question is, is it OK to ignore `keydown` events with `keyCode = 229` if `new String.fromCharCode(229)` returns the printable character "`å`"? I thought about the possible situation of having a real key that produces the same key code and its corresponding character.

I thank you for any kind of help!

Comment: This isn't answering your question directly, but you may use the "input" event to determine when (and only when) the value of your text box changes. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input.

Answer (score 13):

The short answer is No. You can ignore keydown events with keyCode = 229, but only if they follow immediately after a keypress event.

If you hold certain keys down, some browsers send a repeated keydown event with a keyCode value of 229, while others send the original keydown keyCode again. Some browsers send 0 as the keyCode associated with the keypress event, and place the character code in a charCode property.

In all cases, as far as I can tell from my tests, the order of events is always predictable:

```
keydown  (event.keyCode  = key-keyCode            ex: 65 = "A")
keypress (event.keyCode  = 0 | character-keyCode  ex: 97 = "a")  - conflated model
          event.charCode =     character-keyCode                 - split model
keydown  (event.keyCode  = 229 | key-keyCode      ex: 229 | 65)  - may be repeated
keyup    (event.keyCode  = key-keyCode            ex: 65)
```

The [letter å](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%85) is used in a number of Scandinavian languages. Here are the events received in Safari 6.1.5 when the keyboard is set to Swedish or Finnish, and the å character (to the left of the P key) is pressed:

```
EVENT    keyCode
keydown  219     ("[" key position)
keypress 229     (å)
keydown  229     (repeatedly, indicating that the Input Monitor is busy)
keyup    219
```

Notice that the initial keydown keyCode is 219, not 229.

To generate a 229 keyCode on the initial keydown event, you can press any "dead key". On the Swedish keyboard on Mac, for example, the key immediately to the left of of the BACKSPACE key is ´ (acute accent), as used in words like déjà-vu. When you press a dead key, the character appears in the input field, but the insertion point does not move. When you subsequently type a character that can be combined with it, the browser may replace the initial dead key character with a composite character (´ + e = é) which has its own Unicode value.

Here are the events that you will see in Safari 6.1.5 when the user presses and releases ´ followed by e on a Swedish keyboard:

```
EVENT    keyCode
keydown  229 (dead key)
keyup    187 (acute accent)
keydown  229 (second key is being treated)
keyup     69 ("E")
```

Note that there are no keypress events sent at all, because there is no "é" key as such which has been pressed. If you want to determine which character the user entered, you can wait until after the second keyup, then read the character from the input field.

In other words, you can ignore any keydown events with a 229 keyCode *after* a keypress event, but if you ignore all 229 keyCodes, you may prevent users from adding various diacritical characters.

For more information on keyCode 229, from the w3.org site: [keyCode property of key events](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-dom/2010JulSep/att-0182/keyCode-spec.html)

Comment: As recommended by [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keydown_event): Since Firefox 65, the `keydown` and `keyup` events are now fired during IME composition (bug 354358). This code ignores all `keydown` events that are part of composition (229 is a special value set for a keyCode relating to an event that has been processed by an IME): `if (event.isComposing || event.keyCode === 229) return;`