# Keycode value is return as 229 for all keys

Tags: javascript, android, jquery

I have run the normal textbox in android device an i have face some issues which is mentioned below.

1.Keypress event does not triggered in android device
2.keycode value always return as 229 only

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Capture keys typed on android virtual keyboard using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30743490/capture-keys-typed-on-android-virtual-keyboard-using-javascript)

Comment: Hi billyonecan 
Same issue is for me,Thanks
But i cant find any solution from that.Can you please explain what solution is given there?

Comment: You can check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25043934/is-it-ok-to-ignore-keydown-events-with-keycode-229

Comment: Try in Firefox browser in Android devices.

Answer (score 4):

Normal keypress event does not give keyCode in android device. There has already been a big [discussion](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=118639) on this.

If you want to capture the press of `space bar` or `special chars`, you can use `keyup` event.

```
$('#input').on('keyup', e => {
     var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
     if (keyCode == 0 || keyCode == 229) { 
         keyCode = e.target.value.charAt(e.target.selectionStart - 1).charCodeAt();             
     }
})
```

Comment: Is it possible only get ascii code from this? Any other solutions?

Comment: On my computer '$' is 52, on Android Chrome it's 36...

Answer (score 0):

just check your input characters keyCode, if it is 0 or 229 then here is the function **getKeyCode** which uses **charCodeAt** of JS to return the KeyCode which takes input string a parameter and returns keycode of last character.

```
<script>
        var getKeyCode = function (str) {
            return str.charCodeAt(str.length);
        }


        $('#myTextfield').on('keyup',function(e){

            //for android chrome keycode fix
            if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)) {

                var inputValue = this.value;

                var charKeyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
                if (charKeyCode == 0 || charKeyCode == 229) { 
                    charKeyCode = getKeyCode(inputValue);
                    alert(charKeyCode+' key Pressed');
                }else{
                   alert(charKeyCode+' key Pressed');
                    }
            }       
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: This wont work if you type in the middle of the string:

imagine this is the input
[          ]
type in something
[something]
tap in the middle
[some|thing]
type "a"
[someathing]
alert says "g key Pressed"

Comment: e.target.value.charAt(e.target.selectionStart - 1).charCodeAt()