# How to detect enter key on mobile web for div contenteditable

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a mobile web app that requires an `input` field that wraps text. So I
thought I'd use `div` with `contenteditable`.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9r5u7fgs/

```
<div
  class="text-field"
  contenteditable="true"
/>
```

The "input" field should only be 1 line, so when the user presses "enter" I
want to trigger a POST request with the field contents. I don't want any
newlines in the field.

I thought about listening for `keyup` and checking the `keyCode`. This works
correctly on desktop.

```
document.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
    console.log(`e.keyCode=${e.keyCode} - e.key=${e.key}`);
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        sendContents(e.target.textContent);
    }
});
```

However on mobile browsers, I get different behavior.

- First, the keyCode is always 229 for letters.
- Second, I have to press enter twice to get the expected keyCode.

This is what Android 13 Firefox 108.2.0 shows if I type `f` `<enter>` `<enter>`.

```
e.keyCode=229 - e.key=Process
e.keyCode=229 - e.key=Process
e.keyCode=13 - e.key=Enter
```

Android Chrome 108.0.5359.128 prints something similar.

```
e.keyCode=229 - e.key=Unidentified
e.keyCode=229 - e.key=Unidentified
e.keyCode=13 - e.key=Enter
```

I found this: [Keycode value is return as 229 for all keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39035374/keycode-value-is-return-as-229-for-all-keys)
but it didn't really provide a solution.

Is there a way to detect when a user presses "enter" the first time in a div
contenteditable? Is there another event I should listen to?

Reminder this is for mobile web browsers, not desktop.

Comment: Works as expected: Firefox 108.2.0, Android 12, Keyboard: Fleksy 10.2.7. Note for Chrome: Keycode for chars is allways 229 (as you say), but enter is 13 immediately. Have you used the OS default keyboard?