# Cannot detect key event for Android Barcode Scanner input, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, css, barcode-scanner

### Scope

I am attempting to detect character input from a barcode scanner integrated into a hand-held Android device in a simple web application using JavaScript. Since most barcode scanners behave like a keyboard wedge I am using detecting events `keypress` and/or `keyup` to interpret and handle the character input.

I don't want the character input to populate a text input, so I have assigned the event handler to `document`, however, I know I could also assign it to the `window`.

### Sample Code

My sample code for completing the task looks like this; *This sample doesn't differentiate between keyboard input and scanner input, but I have already solved that problem.*

```
var barcodeString = "";

$(document).keypress(function (event) {
    // If character is carriage-return prevent submit.
    if (event.which === 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    // Append other characters to barcodeString.
    barcodeString += event.key;
});
```

### Problem

My problem is that many devices do not return any readable characters at all. When I monitor the character codes using `event.keyCode` I receive two codes: 229 and 13. This article [W3 keyCode in key events](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-dom/2010JulSep/att-0182/keyCode-spec.html) and this StackOverflow answer [Is it OK to ignore keydown events with keyCode = 229?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25509350/5184889) outlines that the 229 code means the Input Monitor is busy. I can only assume this is either because:

- The barcode scanner locks the Input Monitor upon inserting the characters.
- The speed of the character input causes the Input Monitor to become too busy to detect character input.

Interestingly enough, if I detect `event.keyCode` while scanning the text into a text input, the two character codes: 229 and 13 are detected and *only* afterward the text is then inserted into the text input.

### Devices

The devices I am attempting to implement this on are Nautiz X2 made by the Handheld Group. And another Android device, which I am unable to identify the brand of but seems slightly more generic with different barcode scanning software.

### Workarounds

#### 1

The Handheld Group do provide a JavaScript API for interacting with the Handheld Scanner. The way this works is they provide an APK for a custom browser named: Kiosk Browser and implement the interpretation of the JavaScript specific to the scanner there. Documentation can be found here (it's exceedingly short and not a long read): [JavaScript Scanner Interface](https://developer.handheldgroup.com/Kiosk_Browser/JavaScript-Scanner-Interface.html)

#### 2

The more generic Android device has the ability to 'slow-down' character input on the scanner to make the scanner more compatible with third-party applications. Behold, toggling this option allows me to detect character input. Although `event.key` always returns code 229 (this time from an unreadable character), but `String.fromCharCode(event.which)` will somewhat solve the problem (it doesn't deal with special characters). The Nautiz X2 does not have the option to 'slow-down' input in the software settings.

#### 3

The alternative workaround I have considered is putting a text input onto the web page with the style `display: none` to hide it and use JavaScript to continually set focus on the input. The I can **attempt** to monitor `onChange` and handle the character input. I would really like to avoid this approach.

### Summary

The workarounds I have presented seem awful and the first is not device independent. I was wondering if there is a better place to "dump" text input from the barcode scanner so I can handle it in my application? Or, is there an event I can monitor to detect the character input?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? :D I'm having this exact problem right now. no workarounds of yours are feasible. constantly focusing the input (workaround3) keeps opening the android soft keyboard on the scanner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is late, but I am facing a similar problem with a range of devices including the Zebra TC20 and Chainway C71. After a lot of searching around I found this amazing Codepen sample by Bob Jase. He has documented his solution in the code, but I'll repost it here for archive purposes. [link to his CodePen](https://codepen.io/bobjase/pen/QrQQvd/)

His solution uses a hidden  element to change the focus to from a visible  element and thus hiding the soft android keyboard.

```js
// whenever the visible field gets focused
$("#visibleField").bind("focus", function(e) {
  // silently shift the focus to the hidden select box
  $("#hiddenField").focus();
  $("#cursorMeasuringDiv").css("font", $("#visibleField").css("font"));
});

// whenever the user types on his keyboard in the select box
// which is natively supported for jumping to an <option>
$("#hiddenField").bind("keypress",function(e) {
  // get the current value of the readonly field
  var currentValue = $("#visibleField").val();
  
  // and append the key the user pressed into that field
  $("#visibleField").val(currentValue + e.key);
  $("#cursorMeasuringDiv").text(currentValue + e.key);
  
  // measure the width of the cursor offset
  var offset = 3;
  var textWidth = $("#cursorMeasuringDiv").width();
  $("#hiddenField").css("marginLeft",Math.min(offset+textWidth,$("#visibleField").width()));
  
});
```

```css
#hiddenField {
  height:17px; 
  width:1px;
  position:absolute;
  margin-left:3px;
  margin-top:2px;
  border:none;
  border-width:0px 0px 0px 1px;
}

#cursorMeasuringDiv {
  position:absolute;
  visibility:hidden;
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}

#hiddenField:focus {
  border:1px solid gray;  
  border-width:0px 0px 0px 1px;
  outline:none;
  animation-name: cursor;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes cursor {
    from {opacity:0;}
    to {opacity:1;}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Click on the field and type (it should work even though the field isn't really focused): 
<p />

<!-- must be a select box with no children to suppress the keyboard -->
input: <select id="hiddenField" /> 
<span id="fakecursor" />

<input type="text" readonly="readonly" id="visibleField" />
<div id="cursorMeasuringDiv" />
```

I hope this helps. Again, kudos to Bob for working this out!